# Обработать нажатие кнопки на странице

Tags: java, html, jetty

Как обработать нажатие кнопки на html страннице в сервлете (язык Java).
Вывод кнопки на страницу и попытка обработки нажатия данной кнопки

```
case 2:
 response.getWriter().println( " <p>\n" +
                    "<input type=submit value=\"Registration Car\">\n" +
                    " </p>" );
 while( request.getParameter( "Registration Car" ) !=null )
    response.sendRedirect( "/regCar" );
break;
```

Соответственно, это не работает...

Comment: Собственно это какой-то case какого-то switch непонятно на что реагирующий. И вопрос, зачем вам цикл на одноразовое действие?

Comment: case обрабатывает ошибку, при которой нужно сначала вызвать страницу с кнопкой и при нажатии кнопки перебросить на "/regCar", увидел цикл в примере одном поэтому и поставил, но это никак не влияет, даже пытался бесконечный цикл поставить

Comment: Это не так работает. Сервлет не наблюдает за действиями на странице на стороне клиента. Сервлеты отвечают на запросы, т.е. приходит запрос -> отдаются данные, дальше следующий запрос. Для действий на стороне клиента нужен javascript. Но в вашем случае достаточно создать ещё один сервлет и ссылаться на него из кнопки

Comment: я решил проблему по другому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.getWriter().println( PageGenerator.instance().getPage( "error.html", pageVariables ) );
response.getWriter().println( "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"/carParking\">\n" + 
                              "<input type=submit value=\"Registration Car\" name=\"reg\">\n" +
                              "</form>");
if( request.getParameter( "reg" ) != null )
    response.sendRedirect( "/regCar" );
```

1. кнопку нужно создавать внутри `<form method="POST" action="/..."> ... </form>`
Подробнее: http://htmlbook.ru/html/form
 2. кнопку прописал так `<input type=submit value=\"On button\" name=\"param\">`, можно сделать и через `button` в `name` прописывается параметр который потом можно будет отловить через `request.getParameter( "param" )`